# Writing a file using NPOI

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, npoi

I'm unable to use NPOI to save changes to an xlsx to disk, when attempting to do it from a DLL.

I have a set of data that I'm currently storing in a database, and a home-grown ORM for it.  The home-grown ORM is housed in its own DLL.  I want to write a utility which uses the ORM to take a subset of the data to read/write it. I'm using NPOI (v2.1.3.0) to do it.

The utility calls look like:

```
    private void Test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var model = new ExcelDal(this.filename);
        model.Clients.Save(new Client { 
              DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now, DisplayName = "Test", Male = true
        });
    }
```

And I would expect that I would get an xlsx with a sheet named "Client" and a text column for "DateOfBirth", "DisplayName", and "Male".  A file is indeed created, but attempting to open it fails.  On the other hand, if I replace that code with this, I get exactly what's expected:

```
    private void Test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        ISheet sheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Client");
        MainWindow.Create(sheet, 0, "DateOfBirth", "DisplayName", "Male");
        MainWindow.Create(sheet, 1, "1900/1/1", "Test", "true");

        FileMode mode = File.Exists(this.filename) ? FileMode.Truncate : FileMode.Create;

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(this.filename, mode, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            workbook.Write(fs);
        }
    }

    private static void Create(ISheet sheet, int rowNum, params string[] values)
    {
        IRow row = sheet.CreateRow(rowNum);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            ICell cell = row.CreateCell(i);
            cell.SetCellValue(values[i]);
        }
    }
```

Troubleshooting steps attempted thus far:

- Renamed the created file to a zip and extracted it, it is a valid zip.
- Zipped up the file and renamed it to xlsx, I get a slightly different error, but it still fails to open.
- Everything is .Net 4.5
- Another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838743/trying-to-create-a-new-xlsx-file-using-npoi-and-write-to-it) mentioned using ICreationHelper in the answer to convert string values, so I tried that also, but it didn't change anything.
- A few notes on the ORM, since including all the relevant code might be overkill.  I'm using pretty much the same code as the piece above which works; I built the test code to try to figure out what I was doing wrong, but it baffingly just worked.

This is what the code to set a cell value looks like (note that values have already been toString()'d by the time they get to actually be saved):

```
    public void SetValue(IRow row, string column, string value)
    {
        int columnIndex = this.GetColumnIndex(column);
        ICell cell = ColumnMapping.GetOrCreateCell(row, columnIndex);
        cell.SetCellValue(value);
    }

    private static ICell GetOrCreateCell(IRow row, int columnIndex)
    {
        return row.GetCell(columnIndex) ?? row.CreateCell(columnIndex);
    }
```

This is what the code to save the file looks like:

```
    public void Save()
    {
        FileMode mode = File.Exists(this.filename) ? FileMode.Truncate : FileMode.Create;

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(this.filename, mode, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            this.workbook.Write(fs);
        }
    }
```

I cannot detect any differences.  The only thing that it might be is that one is using NPOI indirectly, through the aforementioned ORM and one is using it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to figure out a way of doing it reliably with NPOI.  The files created by the utility always came out corrupted.  I switched over to EPPlus for xlsx.  The resulting code looks like this:

```
public void SetValue(int row, string column, string value)
{
    row += 2;   //EPPlus is 1-index based, and the first row is the heading
    int columnIndex = this.GetColumnIndex(column);
    this.excelSheet.SetValue(row, columnIndex, value);
}
```

The corresponding code to save the file looks like this:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    //ExcelPackage is gone once it is written out.  It must be re-created.
    this.excelPackage.SaveAs(new FileInfo(this.filename));
    this.excelPackage.Dispose();
}
```

So, the implementation is to add a Flush() which will dispose of the current ExcelPackage, then all of the ExcelSheet currently in memory, then re-initialize all from the file written out.