# Error exporting datatable to excel C#

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, com, office-interop

I'm currently having as issue exporting my DataTable to Excel using Microsoft.Office.Interlope.

> The error that comes up is "winform Additional information: Retrieving
>   the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))."

I've googled around and tried all the resolutions I could find, most being changing the DCOM security permissions on "Microsoft Excel Application" in component services.

The error on excel generates "Cannot use object linking"

This is the code I'm currently using

```
 try {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table = dataset(table);

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            excelApp.Visible = false;
            excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
            excelWorkSheet.Name = table.TableName;

            excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Sample test data";
            excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Date : " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

            excelWorkBook.SaveAs(@"C:/testfolder/test.xlsx");
            excelWorkBook.Close();
            excelApp.Quit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Is anyone familiar with exporting to Excel? Have you come across this error and is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Alternative - Export the data directly from the database in CSV format and open that in excel.

Answer (score 0):

[NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/) is a good open source alternative to using Microsoft.Office.Interop for creating Excel spreadsheets.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838743/trying-to-create-a-new-xlsx-file-using-npoi-and-write-to-it) SO post gives you some sample code on how to accomplish this using NPOI.