# How to create an xls file with NPOI?

Tags: c#, excel

All I want to do is to create a file with 1 line and few columns to make some test.

However I cannot find a simple way to do such a thing. Most help I found seem to also use a database.

I found one that doesn't.

[Trying to create a new .xlsx file using NPOI and write to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838743/trying-to-create-a-new-xlsx-file-using-npoi-and-write-to-it)

However it seems like a little too much for such a simple task. Is there a tool which would allow me to do something as simple as

```
Create file
file.cell[0,0] = ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the EPPlus package.  Find it on NuGet.

```
string fileName = @"C:\test\MyNewExcelFile.xlsx";
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(fileName);
using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile)) // create the xlsx file
{
    // Add a new worksheet on which to put data 
    ExcelWorksheet xlWorksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test");
    // Write data to cell(s)
    xlWorksheet.Cells["A1"] = ...
    // Write the file
    xlPackage.Save();
}
```

**EDIT**

Modification to replace worksheet if it already exists.

```
const string fileName = @"C:\test\MyNewExcelFile.xlsx";
const string sheetName = @"test";

FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(fileName);

using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile)) // create the xlsx file
{
    // if sheet already exists, delete it
    // use LINQ to query collection of worksheets
    ExcelWorksheet xlWorksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.SingleOrDefault(ws => ws.Name == sheetName);
    if (xlWorksheet != null)
    {
        // worksheet exists - delete it
        xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Delete(sheetName);
    }
    // Add new worksheet on which to put data 
    ExcelWorksheet xlWorksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test");
    // Write data to cell(s)
    xlWorksheet.Cells["A1"] = ...
    // Write the file
    xlPackage.Save();
}
```

Comment: How do you write file a second time, this line throws an exception: ExcelWorksheet xlWorksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test");

Comment: @Cher what exception are you seeing?  Perhaps there already exists a sheet with the same name as the one you're attempting to insert.

Comment: thx for anser!! but that is exactly the problem, when I call the method, I would just like to overwrite it if it exist

Comment: So, by overwrite, you mean you'd like to delete the existing sheet and replace it with a new one?  I'll edit my response.